# Parameter of function not available in lambda function in maxima (curried function)

Tags: maxima

I try to write a curried function in maxima, but it seems not to be possible to get the parameter available in the lambda function, this is my code:

```
structp(type) := lambda([struct], is(reveal(struct, 1) = type));
```

I want it to work like this, say I have the:

```
defstruct(a(b,c));
struct: a(1,2);
structp(a)(struct);
```

Where the last should give back true, because the `struct` is of type `a`.

Is it somehow possible to get the parameter available in the lambda function?

I like to use a curried function here, because in that way I can write short code like this:

```
sublist(list_of_structs, structp(a));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions inside of `lambda` are not evaluated until the lambda is applied to an argument. E.g. if you have `f(y) := lambda([x], y*x)` then `f(5)` returns `lambda([x], y*x)` (not `lambda([x], 5*x)` as one might want).

There are at least a couple of ways to get the result you want. I think maybe the most straightforward is `f(y) := subst('y = y, lambda([x], y*x))`. Or in the example you give:

```
structp(type) := 
  subst ('type = type, lambda([struct], is(reveal(struct, 1) = type)));
```

Then `structp(a)` returns `lambda([struct], is(reveal(struct, 1) = a))` as desired.

EDIT: There are other ways to achieve the same effect. Take a look at `buildq`.